# Destruir vários sliders de uma vez

Tags: jquery, html, slider, owl-carousel

Eu quero destruir **todos** meus sliders quando a página bater o tamanho de 768px. Para isso fiz esse código abaixo:

```
if($(window).width() >= 768){
    $(".owl-carousel-linhas").data('owlCarousel').destroy();
}
```

Tenho na minha página vários sliders assim:

```
<div class="owl-carousel-linhas">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel-linhas">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel-linhas">
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
   <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

E o código que fiz acima destrói apenas o primeiro slider, o resto não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver. Foi simples, até.

```
$(".owl-carousel-linhas").each(function (index, obj){
    $(this).data('owlCarousel').destroy();
});
```

Troquei o **obj** por `$(this)`.

Comment: Aqui poderia ser `$(obj)[0].data()` também. Vivendo e desaprendendo.

Answer (score 1):

Baseado no seu comentário, vou fazer uma alteração que talvez resolva o seu problema, colocando esse código dentro do seu `if`:

```
while($(".owl-carousel-linhas").length > 0){
    $($(".owl-carousel-linhas")[0]).data('owlCarousel').destroy();
}
```

Verifique se isso resolve o seu problema.

Comment: Já tentei isso. Mas como ele destrói o primeiro, não acha o segundo... é o que parece. Vou simular o erro para te mostrar.
`Uncaught TypeError: e.data is not a function`.